# Script to Create Copy (Backup) of entire spreadsheet onOpen

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is it possible to write a script or is there another method of backing up a spreadsheet when opened?

The reason is: I have other users opening my spreadsheets and if they completely stuff everything up I want to be able to go to a backup created when they first opened my doc.

Comment: Thank you I was not familiar with this feature. :-| Still learning!!

Comment: No problem. I turned my comment in an answer, so that you can accept it (and this thread gets an 'answered' status).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the built-in *revision history*, that's available in both the spreadsheet and the script editor under the first menu option (File).

Read the Google Help for more info: [revision history](http://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en)